# regexpr: extract part of a string containing a specific e-mail address

Tags: regex, string, string-matching

Working with regular expression is always a nightmare (to me!). I don't have clearly understand the difference between greedy and ungreedy search and how to activate one or the other :(

I have a CSV file like this:

```
row1, value2, value3, value4
row2, value2, value3, value4
"Main string", "secondary string", "name1.surname1@whatever-host.com, name2.surname2@whatever-host.com, stefano.test@whatever-host.com,name4.surname4@whatever-host" "footer"
"ABC", "ABC", "stefano.test@whatever-host.com"  "last-row-value"
row5, value2, value3, value4
"Main string", "secondary string", "stefano.test@whatever-host.com"  "last-row-value"
"stefano.test@whatever-host.com, another.account@whatever-host.com", 2, 3, 4
row999, value2, value3, value4
```

My goal (with regexpr) is to extract only the (full) string on rows containing "stefano.test@whatever-host.com":

```
"name1.surname1@whatever-host.com, name2.surname2@whatever-host.com, stefano.test@whatever-host.com,name4.surname4@whatever-host"
"stefano.test@whatever-host.com"
"stefano.test@whatever-host.com"
"stefano.test@whatever-host.com, another.account@whatever-host.com"
```

I've started from this regexpr...

```
(").*(stefano\.test@whatever-host\.com).*(")
```

...but it gets me the full (original) string. Which regexpr operator should I use?

Comment: Input is string or list of string?

Comment: @HiralTalsaniya, input is a csv file containing several string on the same row.
Thanks for observation. I've modified the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if it is fine for you

```
import csv,re
with open('test1', newline='') as f:

    for line in  csv.reader(f, quotechar='"', delimiter=' ',
                         quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
        # print(l)
        for data in line:
            match = re.search('@whatever-host.com',data)
            if match:
                print(data)
```

Output:

```
name1.surname1@whatever-host.com, name2.surname2@whatever-host.com, stefano.test@whatever-host.com,name4.surname4@whatever-host
stefano.test@whatever-host.com
stefano.test@whatever-host.com
stefano.test@whatever-host.com, another.account@whatever-host.com,
```

Comment: Sorry for not being accurate on the request. I don't have an array of string but a CSV file instead containing different data including "somewhere" a mailing list. I need to find out where my e-mail is contained together with any other e-mail addresses of the same list.

Comment: @StefanoRadaelli I have updated it please check it.